# Apache2 redirect to central cgi script

Tags: redirect, python-3.x, apache2

I configured my apache2 so it redirects all requests to the index.py at the top level of /var/www following [this](http://www.dreamsolution.nl/blog/2010-10-17-apache-fallback-handler.php) guide. Now i have the problem that i ever become this error when opening a site which is not the index.py itself:

You don't have permission to access /index.py/ on this server.

Where after the /index.py the actual url typed appears. So if i try to open the url /abc the file to open would be /index.py/abc. How can i avoid this so just index.py is opened?

EDIT: I found the command RedirectMatch which doesn't work because the URL needs to be saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now use a rewrite engine with the following commands in the .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/index.py|/downloads)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.py?url=$1
```